# proving how many permutations exist.

Tags: combinatorics, permutation-cycles

Show that the number of permutations of n numbers, for n ≥ 2, with two cycles is at most
(n−1)!logn.

Unsure as to were to start any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The number of cycle permutations on $k$ letters is $(k-1)!$ If your cycles are of lengths $m$ and $n-m,$ you have $\binom{n}{m} (m-1)! (n-m-1)!$ possibilities, so
your total is
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{m} (m-1)! (n-m-1)! = n!\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m(n-m)}.$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: no still a bit confused sorry.

Comment: @JamesWiseman confused where?

Comment: how do you incorporate the bit about n being greater than or equal to into the above

Comment: @JamesWiseman Maybe you should try to understand this answer for more than 60 seconds.